# Show page content on another page using views

Tags: 7, views, entities, media, files

I have a 'presentation' page where I would like an image gallery where all the uploaded images that users upload to the site are displayed.

So far these images are being displayed only on the 'upload' page as default.
(users are effectively modifying the same page when adding content)

I want to keep the 'upload' only as means to upload the images but I want all the images to be displayed **ONLY** on the 'presentation' page!

How do I do it with views?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but you can create two view modes for the node that contains all the images that users upload, one for 'presentation' and one for 'upload' using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (see [tutorial on view modes](https://drupalize.me/videos/display-suite-view-modes?p=1141)). If you don't want the upload version to show the images, simply hide the Image field in the 'upload' view mode.

Additionally, you can use a module like [Juicebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox) to create a nice-looking and easy to navigate Javascript gallery in the 'presentation' view mode - just select "Juicebox Gallery" as the formatter for the Image field (instead of the default Image formatter) in your 'presentation' view mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view block
2. Create custom page or your defined page.
3. Open views block configuration select option show block on specific page